# Highlighting a text box using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, textbox, frontend

Is it possible to highlight the border of a text box/make the background colour of a text box change colour, when clicked using jquery?

All I can find are pieces of code relating to highlighting text inside the text box, not the box itself.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "*highlight the border*" - changing the `border-color`?

Comment: you are referring to either `background-color: blue` or `border-color: blue`

Comment: Have you already checked out this http://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-corners-borders/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("#mytextbox").focus(function(){
  $(this).addClass("focused");
});

$("#mytextbox").blur(function(){
  $(this).removeClass("focused");
});
```

```css
.focused{
  border: solid 1px red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="mytextbox" value="Hello There !" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this method but couldn't get it working. Can't seem to find the problem as to why though, its my first time using jquery and I'm a complete novice with coding anyway

Comment: are you getting any JS error. able to see something in firebug or browser console

Comment: I think it's to do with the script src. I have a calendar function in on a text box after the one I wish to highlight which brings up a calendar and allows you to click a date. If I add the script src you have provided within the <head> it disables the calendar script src I have in the head but still doesn't make the focus and blur work either

Comment: sorry, but i can't guess whats going wrong at your end. If possible, can you please share your code.

Comment: I got it working, I hadn't included   $(function() {     before the code. Only problem is now it only works on the first text box and not all of the ones with the id="mytextbox"

Comment: in that case i will suggest to add unique class to all your required textboxes lets say `class="mytextboxes"` and in JavaScript code instead of `$("#mytextbox").`; go for `$(".mytextboxes").`

Answer (score 1):

You change the css `class` of the textbox.  Within the css class you specify the border etc, eg:

```
$(function() {
    $("#textboxid").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("textboxhighlight");
    });
});
```

then add some css:

```
.textboxhighlight {
    background-color: red;
}
```

---

Edit: As per question "when clicked" - but it may be more prudent to change on focus/blur

Answer (score 0):

On focus it will change the color of the background of the input to yellow as to "highlight" it, on blur it will change it back:

```
$("input text").on("focus", function(){
    $(this).attr("background-color", "yellow");
}

$("input text").on("blur", function(){
        $(this).attr("background-color", "transparent");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="mytextbox" value="Hello There !" />
```

`$("#mytextbox").focus(function(){
  $(this).addClass("focused");
});`

`.focused{
   border-color: #a94442 !important;
}`

http://jsfiddle.net/apurva_prajapati/zepy2ogh/

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#mytextbox").onchange(function(){
  $(this).addClass("focused");
});

$("#mytextbox").blur(function(){
  $(this).removeClass("focused");
});
```

```css
.focused{
  border: solid 1px red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="mytextbox" value="Hello There !" />
```